# How to read data from a tsv file in the default data formats which are mixed up and randomly arranged in columns and rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

Let's assume that I want to read data like shown below from tsv file

```
4 4.000 one 57.3800 57 4
3 3.000 1 57.3800 seven 3
```

I do this in this way

```
df_data = pd.read_csv('./models' + file_path, sep='\t', index_col=False, header=None,
                      skip_blank_lines=False, keep_default_na=False, names=columns)
```

when I check the format of the data

```
for index, row in df_data.head(2).iterrows():

    for index, key in enumerate(input):

        print(type(row[key]))
        print(row[key])
```

it returns

```
<type 'float'>
4.0
<type 'float'>
4.0
<type 'str'>
one
<type 'float'>
57.38
<type 'float'>
57.0
<type 'float'>
4.0

<type 'float'>
3.0
<type 'float'>
3.0
<type 'float'>
1.0
<type 'float'>
57.38
<type 'str'>
seven
<type 'float'>
3.0
```

but it should look like this

```
<type 'integer'>
4
<type 'float'>
4.0
<type 'str'>
one
<type 'float'>
57.38
<type 'integer'>
57
<type 'integer'>
4


<type 'integer'>
3
<type 'float'>
3.0
<type 'integer'>
1
<type 'float'>
57.38
<type 'str'>
seven
<type 'integer'>
3
```

So as you can see I need to preserve the same data types that were before reading tsv file. So I have three types - int, string and float. They are mixed up and randomly arranged in columns and rows. So there is not a single row, which for example has only integers or column with only strings. Like in the example above. So there is no possibility to cast for example whole column. I just need to read them by default. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

What do you think about solution shown below? If anyone has any comments, tips, improvements, I will be grateful for sharing them.

```
def int_or_float(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except:
            return s

with open('./models' + file_path) as tsvfile:

    data = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")

    for index, row in enumerate(data):

        row = [int_or_float(el) for el in row]

        for index2, key2 in enumerate(input):

            print(type(row[key2]))
            print(row[key2])
```

Comment: Write the reason when you downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `pd.read_csv()` ...
>
> there is no possibility to cast for example whole column.

You are using the wrong tool for the task at hand.

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is for structured columnar data.
Your problem definition tells us that your data lacks structure.

Also, you didn't tell us what you want to do with the dataframe after you read it.

For uniform handling of values you might find it helpful
to prepend a nonsense string to each one that you read in,
e.g. `'value: '`, so pandas isn't tempted to cast to float or int.

The [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) appears to be a better fit for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question. Can you take a look on my solution and write what do you think?